# How do I create a new record in a table according to primary key of another tab in an Access Form?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, primary-key, data-entry

I have two tables. The first one is the list of my customers with their auto-generated ID, their name and their status in my DB. The second table is the list of my customers' phone numbers and whether it is a mobile or landline. One customer can have many phone numbers, that is why I keep in every record in table2 the CustomerID.

I want to create a form that allows me to add a new customer to my list, and in a separate form, add one or more phone numbers ACCORDING to the CustomerID I've just add. In the future I will have many more tables like Customer_Phones_List also linked to Customers_List so I'm not sure if a subform is the best option.

How do I do that in MS Access ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Build form/subform(s) arrangement. Can use a tab control for multiple subforms to conserve screen space. Each page of tab control can have a subform that is linked to data on main form.